# writing a GridCacheStore implementation in scala with gridgain

Tags: scala, gridgain

Im trying to write a gridgain implementation for read-through and write-through for gridcache using scala. however im having trouble converting some of the method patterns using generics form java (which is what its written in) to scala.

java doc in question:
http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc30C/org/gridgain/grid/cache/GridCacheStore.html

specifically

```
loadAll(String cacheName, GridCacheTx tx, Collection<? extends K> keys, GridInClosure2<K,V> c)
```

i'm having trouble with

```
Collection<? extends K> keys
```

since i dont know how to do that in scala. So if anyone can show me the best way to do this in scala, that would be awsome. Unfortunately the awesome gridgain javadocs dont have much in the way of scala examples yet. Also can I safely ignore the GridCacheTx tx since im not going to be using transactions in my application.

Answer (score 2):

Existential types were created for this situation. See [Combining Scala and Java](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combining-scala-and-java.html#29.3) in the now free online first edition of *Programming in Scala*.

So you may need to define:

```
def loadAll(cacheName: String, tx: GridCacheTx, 
  keys:Collection[T] forSome {T <: K}, 
  c: GridInClosure2[K,V])
```

I think `Collection[_ <: K]` may also work.

I also read somewhere that *abstract types* could be used to handle a similar situation too, but I can't find the link now, so I'm not sure whether it covered this case or not. *edit: actually it's in the book too (the SetAndType example in the next paragraph)*.

Comment: this works to the point of compiling it. Then it says it does not match the interface definition.

Comment: You mean it compiles and you get a runtime error? Without more info I'm afraid I don't have any other insights.